# Screen vs. print behavior for an HTML and CSS document

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand screen vs. print behavior. What's the reason the [APSW docs](http://apsw.googlecode.com/svn/publish/index.html) look different in print vs. screen? (In print, the table of contents column vanishes, and the main column takes up the whole print width)

(I'm trying to debug my sphinx document which doesn't have this behavior, but I figure if I can understand one that works properly, I can figure out why mine doesn't.)

---

Just something to note, after looking closely at the `@media print` section in basic.css cited by those of you who answered — there was one line different between my basic.css and the one in APSW:

```
div.bodywrapper {
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `!important` modifier was missing from my basic.css and that was causing the `margin: 0` to get overridden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done using [media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). With them, you can limit style rules to a certain output device like screen, printer, or handheld.
See here: http://apsw.googlecode.com/svn/publish/_static/basic.css

Comment: I know about media types, but as far as I can tell the APSW docs make no reference to media types.

Comment: Actually, they do. So don't downvote an answer, just because you can't read.
See: http://apsw.googlecode.com/svn/publish/_static/basic.css

Comment: I've been looking for the past 30 minutes and can't find it. If you edit your answer to point it out, I'll upvote you. Sorry.

Comment: ARGH: I found it. Thanks. Please tweak your answer so I can upvote it + accept (first post)

Comment: Accepted. (can't rescind my downvote for some reason.... maybe you have to edit it after the initial time-period runs out?)

Comment: @Pekka: could you insert a space or something so I can upvote?

Answer (score 2):

This is linked to the [media type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).

You can either link it to a group of properties:

```
@media screen {
    body { font-size: 13px }
  }
```

or to an entire stylesheet

```
<link href="blah.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In your case:

```
@media print {
    div.document,
    div.documentwrapper,
    div.bodywrapper {
        margin: 0 !important;
        width: 100%;
    }

    div.sphinxsidebar,
    div.related,
    div.footer,
    #top-link {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They have [@media rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#at-media-rule).

Comment: Geez... I'm sorry, I looked for 30 minutes in the source files for the APSW docs and couldn't find it. I overlooked it in a 2nd level import document, and saw an answer posted here that made a statement about those source files w/o referencing a particular location. I'll be less quick to downvote in the future, managed to undo it before the clock ran out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:
http://apsw.googlecode.com/svn/publish/_static/basic.css

They include another css-file in their stylesheet via
@import url("basic.css");